# Why is there a negative in Joint probability density?

Tags: probability-distributions, stochastic-calculus

From the book of O. Calin (An Informal Introduction to Stochastic Calculus with Applications)

> Lemma 4.7.1. The joint density function of $(W_t,M_t)$ is given by
> $$f(a,b) = \dfrac{2(2b-a)}{\sqrt{2 \pi} t^{\frac{3}{2}}} e^{-\dfrac{(2b-a)^2}{2t}}, ~~~ a \leq b, b \geq 0.$$

Here, we define $W_t$ be a standard Brownian motion and
$$M_t = \max_{0 \leq s \leq t} W_s.$$

Part of the proof of Lemma 4.7.1
The associated probability density $f(a,b)$ can be obtained by differentiation

[image]

My question is ``Why there is a negative sign before the limit?''

I found this on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function), to solve the joint probability density can be computed by getting the partial derivatives
[image]
with the condition that all $X_n \leq x_n$. However, in my case is that, $M_t \geq b$.

Thank you for giving ideas.

Comment: Note that we have $(a,a-\Delta a)$ in the numerator while we $\Delta a=(a+\Delta a)-a$ in the denominator.

Comment: Thank you sir drhab

Answer (score 1):

Using conditional probability formula,
\begin{eqnarray}
P(W_t \leq a, M_t \geq b) &=& P(W_t \leq a) P(M_t \geq b | W_t \leq a) \\
&=& P(W_t \leq a) \Big( 1- P(M_t \leq b | W_t \leq a) \Big) \\
&=& P(W_t \leq a) - P(W_t \leq a) P(M_t \leq b | W_t \leq a) \\
&=& P(W_t \leq a) - P(M_t \leq b , W_t \leq a).
\end{eqnarray}
Differentiate $\Big(\dfrac{\partial^2}{\partial a \partial b}\Big)$,
\begin{eqnarray}
\dfrac{\partial^2}{\partial a \partial b}  P(W_t \leq a, M_t \geq b) &=&  \dfrac{\partial^2}{\partial a \partial b}  P(W_t \leq a) -\dfrac{\partial^2}{\partial a \partial b}P(M_t \leq b , W_t \leq a) \\
&=& - f(a,b).
\end{eqnarray}

Thanks to Ovidiu Calin for this answer.